# Customers who bought the exact 2 items

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `order_details` which contains 3 columns `order_id`, `customer_id`, and `item_name`

I need to find the `customer_id`s of those customers who bought **both** `Kindle` and `Alexa`

This is how my table looks like.

[image]

These are the DML and DDL commands for your reference:

```
create table personal.order_details(
order_id varchar(10),
customer_id varchar(10),
item_name varchar(10))

insert into personal.order_details values
('1000','C01','Alexa'),
('1000','C01','Kindle'),
('1001','C02','Alexa'),
('1002','C03','Alexa'),
('1002','C03','Kindle')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select od.customer_id
from personal.order_details od
where od.item_name in ('Alexa', 'Kindle')    -- rows that have either
group by od.customer_id
having count(distinct od.item_name) = 2;     -- customers that have both
```